# How to answer if interviewer ask how do you test e-commerce site

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, test-design, testcase, qa-developer

Once interviewer asked me how you gonna test the e-commerce site, i tried to explain flow wise and module wise but he looks unhappy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test a toaster? (interview question)](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10026/how-to-test-a-toaster-interview-question)

Answer (score 1):

what kind of e-commerce ? which function need to test ? do you intend to talk all cases of e-commerce site in the interview ?

I think the main point of this question is to see how deep you go to collect/clarify information from client/stakeholder, NOT how to test :)